# LinkedIn "Email" Client

Tags: desktop-client, linkedin

LinkedIn is getting more and common. I get tons of important messages and I need more of desktop or gmail style client than the built in one. But I don't see anything, aside from perhaps outreach.io, which is mega expensive. Anything else out there which is a LinkedIn client or way to download LinkedIn messages? Aside from LinkedIn Desktop.